# Winforms form border styles FixedSingle and FixedDialog?

Tags: c#, winforms

What's the difference between the Winforms form border styles `FixedSingle` and `FixedDialog`?

Despite the [MSDN docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hw8kes41(v=vs.110).aspx), there is no difference in the appearance of either border style on Windows 7:

[image]

Comment: See [FormBorderStyle Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hw8kes41(v=vs.110).aspx).  You can really see the difference on a computer from 1995.

Comment: Not my downvote, but if things are right there on MSDN the question does lack of reaserch.

Comment: @TaW I read the MSDN documentation and understand the explanation, however I still do not see a difference and thus my question.

Comment: I did my own testing @reformed and saw that the only visual difference was that the Form Icon is not displayed when FormBorderStyle is changed to `FixedDialog`. I think that there was probably a bigger difference in previous versions of Windows.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hw8kes41(v=vs.110).aspx):

> FixedDialog: A thick, fixed dialog-style border.
>
> FixedSingle: A fixed, single-line border.

Also, while the date shows it might be out-dated, [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984300(v=vs.71).aspx) is another possible description of the differences:

> Fixed Dialog: Used for dialog boxes. Not resizable. Can include control-menu box, title bar, Maximize and Minimize buttons on the title bar. ***Creates a recessed border relative to the body of the form.***
>
> Fixed Single: Not resizable. Can include control-menu box, title bar, Maximize button, and Minimize button. Resizable only using Maximize and Minimize buttons. ***Creates a single line border***.

Emphasis mine.